# Parsing valid JSON throwing errors

Tags: ruby, json

I’m confused as to why this throws an error:

```
s = <<JSON
{"s": "This is \"valid\" JSON"}
JSON

JSON.parse(s) # => JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '{"s": "This is "valid" JSON"}'
```

Based on using http://jsonlint.com I can confirm that this is valid JSON, so what’s the deal? I get the feeling that I could be using `%q{}` here and things would be escaped properly, but I’d really rather use a heredoc here.

Answer (score 10):

It turns out that Ruby [supports disabling interpolation in heredocs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html) by surrounding the opening identifier with single quotes, so in my example above, it would look like this:

```
s = <<'JSON'
{"s": "This is \"valid\" JSON"}
JSON

JSON.parse(s) # => {"s"=>"This is \"valid\" JSON"}
```